# Single Window Menu screen in Nexus 5

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, multi-window

I am using Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.2. Its menu screen contains "3 screens" to accommodate all the apps I have. But I remember in older Android (I think I saw it in Galaxy S phone) that all the apps were put in single screen and we could scroll down to get any app.

So I want to change this "multi-window" menu screen to a single scrollable window.

Is it possible in KitKat? if so, how?

Comment: I don't think the Google Experience launcher has this customisation. You could install a third party launcher like Nova or Apex that should have this

Comment: @RossC, I'd say that qualifies as a full-on answer. If you post it as an answer, I'd certainly upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently on the [nexus-5](/questions/tagged/nexus-5) stock launcher the 'Google Experience Launcher' or 'GEL' for short, there is no way to customise the app picker / app drawer. You could install a free third party launcher such as [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en_GB) which I have checked and it has a 'List' option, or [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher)

The potential downside to a third party launcher is you will lose the Google Now integration on the left most homescreen and the Ok google functionality.

Comment: You can endure it or get rid of GEL. Google may release updates with more functionality in the future, but to be honest they've stuck with Horizontal scrolling for a long time now and I don't anticipate any change.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK - there's no reason that you have to endure it. You can install any of a large selection of high quality third-party launchers that have this feature. You would lose the ability to say "Okay Google" to get to GNow, but Google Now itself is still available in the same way it was before 4.4 - by dragging up from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @dotVezz yeah I do agree, personally I'm a big fan of Nova Launcher, but I had to add the warning that you lose OK Google functionality AND the leftmost screen / google now integration which may be a factor in changing launcher, depending on personal preference.